# Programmatically create a node with a custom namespace in ROS 1

Tags: ros, python, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I wanted to know if there is a way to create programmatically in Python a ROS Node with a certain namespace decided by me. I know that in ROS 2 this is possible but I can't seem to find anything similar to it on ROS.
I'm using ROS Noetic and Python 3.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353549/programmatically-create-a-node-with-a-custom-namespace-in-ros-1/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the namespace can be set programmatically in ROS 1 by setting `ROS_NAMESPACE` prior to importing `rospy`. With the code below, the node will have the namespace `/my/custom/namespace` unless the user running the node sets `ROS_NAMESPACE` or passes the command line argument `__ns:=/some/other/ns`.

```
import os
import sys

if 'ROS_NAMESPACE' not in os.environ:
    # Default namespace if not set
    # Note, didn't need to check sys.argv for `__ns:=...`,
    # it seems __ns:= takes precidence over ROS_NAMESPACE

    os.environ['ROS_NAMESPACE'] = '/my/custom/namespace'


# Must set `os.environ['ROS_NAMESPACE']` BEFORE importing `rospy`
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import String

rospy.init_node('listener_default_ns')
rospy.Subscriber("chatter", String, lambda m: rospy.loginfo(m.data))
rospy.spin()
```

I tested this using ROS Melodic, but I would expect it to work in ROS Noetic as well.

---

**EDIT** @gvdhoorn has a good point. While the above answers the literal question, the preferred approach is to set the namespace when starting the nodes. The code of a node should only focus on its purpose; it shouldn't have to be concerned about whether there is one or many robots in different namespaces using that node. The awareness of how the node is integrated into a larger system should only be with the tools that launch the node.

You already discovered it can be set using the `ns` attribute in launch files. The namespace can be set one node at a time, or on a whole group of nodes at once. I took [this example from the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#A_More_Complicated_Example) and simplified it for this answer.

```
<launch>
  <!-- Start a single node in the namespace foo -->
  <node ns="foo" name="listener1" pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="listener"/>
  <!-- Start a group of nodes in the namespace bar-->
  <group ns="bar">
    <node pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="listener" name="listener"/>
    <node pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="talker" name="talker"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-29**:
It would perhaps also be good to ask *why* the OP wants to do this, as placing nodes in namespaces (and remapping topics, setting parameters, etc) are typically considered either configuration or deployment time activities.

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-05-29**:
Thank you! This works yes! Another way I found was to put the namespace on the launch file using the field 'ns'.
I want to do this because I want to have a multi-robot system where each robot has the same number of servers and each one accesses their corresponding servers.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-05-29**:
Ah got it. Updated answer to describe how to change the namespace using launch files.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-29**:
@PedroACaldeira: please use the approach shown by @sloretz. Do not put nodes in namespaces by changing `os.environ` manually inside the nodes themselves.